# Clear IBDesignable views have black background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, interface-builder, ibdesignable

I'm attempting to create an IBDesignable class which can have a transparent background when rendered in Interface Builder. So far, I've gotten opaque black backgrounds. I've set up a simple demonstration of the issue:

I've placed a UIView in this scene in Interface Builder. You can't see it because its background is clear. This is what should the scene *should* look like.

[image: A screenshot of an empty scene in interface builder]

The only difference in this screenshot is that I've set the class of our previously invisible view to be 'DesignableView'.

[image: A screen shot of an Interface Builder scene with a black box in the middle]

Here is the entire implementation of the DesignableView class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface DesignableView : UIView
@end

@implementation DesignableView
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    //rendering code goes here
}
@end
```

Is there a way to give the IBDesignable view the correct, transparent background?

Comment: If you're not using `drawRect:` you should comment it out; it effects performance. That might also be the issue

Comment: It's true having an empty implementation of `drawRect:` is a bad idea, however that point is not relevant for this question. In this example, the `drawRect:` function is empty because it's the simplest way to reproduce the issue of having a black background in IB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just remembered how I fix this. You need to override `layoutSubviews`

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris! This works great. I've found that this trick also works when the call to set `self.backgroundColor` is made in the `prepareForInterfaceBuilder` function, which might be a preferable place.